# Find difference between two Matrix/Vectors in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix, subtraction

I have two matrix and want to get difference(Subtraction) b/w two matrix

e.g, IF

```
A = [2 4 6]
B = [1 1 1]
```

Answer should be

```
ans = [1 3 5]      % A-B
```

Note:
(Its not a set difference..)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use one of the following in Matlab:

1. `A-B`
2. `minus(A,B)`

You will get:

```
ans =

    1     3     5
```

Check out [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/minus.html) for more info.